# What is a good mysql view editor?

Tags: mysql

I have tried HeidiSQL and ToadMySQL.  The problem with these editors is when I want to edit a view, they put the whole query on one line. What I want, is each select clause on its own line, the from on its on line, each join on its own line, and each where clause on its own line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbForge Studio - the best http://www.devart.com/. It's free. I have tried Toad and EMC too, but returned to dbForge